# Not able to install PHP5-dev in 13.04

Tags: apt, php

I'm trying to run phpize in ubuntu. However, it seems that the php5dev is not installed.

So I run

```
apt-get install php5-dev
```

However the terminal returning some error messages :

```
Err http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates/main linux-libc-dev i386 3.8.0-30.44
404  Not Found
 Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security/main linux-libc-dev i386 3.8.0-30.44
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
 Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-  dev_3.8.0-30.44_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
 E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
 myuser@myserver:/tmp/upgrade/gearman-1.0.2$ lsb_release -a
 No LSB modules are available.
 Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
 Description:   Ubuntu 13.04
 Release:   13.04
 Codename:  raring
```

Is there anything I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Running `apt-get update` and redoing `apt-get install` seems solve the problem.